# How can i select last 10 charge code that user bought?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in mysql that has three column , one is the code that user bought it, the others is the time that this code has bought and last one is the buyers phone number; for exampale :

```
#CODE          #phone        #date
2154856265     3214490       2013-08-15
```

so now how can i make a query in php format that return me this statement :
i want the last 10 code that the user = 3214490 ordered by the date?

thanks for your patient ;)

Comment: filter out the ones made by that user, order from most recent time and take the last 10.  How you actually implement that can be sorted out by a simple google

Comment: And Google is populated with results from Stack Overflow and other question / answer sites, so why not help improve Google's results by giving the answer instead of a vague description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're kidding, right? This is about as trivial a query as they get.

```
select code
from table
where phone = 3214490
order by date desc
limit 10
```

Comment: thank you Barmer! befor i don't know how to use desc but now it's obvious for me, i learn new thing thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:-

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM table where user = 3214490 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10
) sub
ORDER BY date ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using 'phone' for the user id, you want a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [table_name] WHERE `phone` = 3214490 ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 10
```

Replace [table_name] with the name of the table these records are stored in, as you didn't specify it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.code from directory c where c.phone= '3214490' order by c.date limit 0,10
```

This might help